# Error with Chinese characters in creating notebook: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am using the r notebook. The problem is when add Chinese character levels or column in the data table, the application always says,

> error creating notebook: non-numeric argument to binary operator.

I know there are something incompatible between r notebook and Chinese characters.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

My code is here.

```
(
  y <- data_frame(
    x = c("cmstr", "cmbool", "cmnum")
  ) %>%
  mutate(x = as.factor(x)) %>%
  mutate(x = fct_recode(x, 
    "一" = "cmstr",
    "二" = "cmbool",
    "三" = "cmnum"
  ))
)
```

[image: r notebook error creating notebook: non-numeric argument to binary operator]